# Delivering a Java application with SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jar

I have developed a Java project that uses an SQL Server 2008 Database. Now if I want to deliver this Java application to any person such as client that will practically implement my Java application into his/her use, how will I deliver the database that is used to store the data used by the application? i-e I need to deliver the database with jar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking how to package an MS SQLServer database in a java jar file?

That's just not possible, sorry. SQLServer is a commercial, platform-specific (Windows), native application, so the will have to be installed by the 'client'.

If you really need to embed the database in your application, and don't absolutely need to use SQL Server, there are several Java-based, embeddable databases available, such as HSQLDB, H2, Derby, SQLite, etc.

Comment: OK, I understand. But then how can I give the whole SQL Server database to the client when I can't even copy and paste the database file?

Comment: You would need to export the database and give the result to the client to import.

Comment: But that will essentially require the client to have SQL Server 2008 management studio installed on his/her PC, isn't it?

Comment: If Yes, then will the client have to permanently install management studio or he can delete after restoring? And also, making a backup as you said, also transfers data already existing in the database?

Comment: You don't seem to be grasping the concept. For a client to use SQL Server at all, they must have it "permanently" installed. You seem to have a requirement for an embedded database, and SQL Server does not meet that requirement. I suggest that you research embedded databases like the ones that I mentioned, and not try to use one of the server-installed databases (like MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postgresql, etc.).

Comment: OK, I got it. Actually I didn't have any kind of such requirement. I was asking just for the sake of personal knowledge and experience. Thank you. @GreyBeardedGeek